# repeat span on screen javascript

Tags: javascript, html, repeat

I wand to repeat a span with javascript over the whole screen. But, I don't know how i do it. 
My code is:

CSS:

```
span.box{
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    position: absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="box">Some content</span>
```

And here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GBXV/).

Thanks in javascript. (not to advanced plz. I'm not the best with javascript)

Comment: This is something that you could learn how to do by picking up a book or reading a couple of tutorials on the DOM (`createElement`) and for...loops.

Comment: I'm following a javascript tutorial on the internet now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

In your *very specific* case something like this might be what you are looking for:
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6MqKm/)

CSS

```
span.box {
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var ww = window.innerWidth,
    wh = window.innerHeight,
    ew = 125, // element width in px 
    eh = 125, // element height in px 
    xn = Math.floor( ww / ew ), // elements per row
    yn = Math.floor( wh / eh ), // rows
    n = xn * yn; // number of elements

for( var i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {

    var box = document.createElement( "span" ),
        txt = document.createTextNode( "Some content" );

    box.className = "box";
    box.appendChild( txt );
    document.body.appendChild( box );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addSpan(n, content){
  var body = document.getElementByTagName('body');
  var item = '<span class="box">'+content+'</span>';
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    body.innerHTML += item;
  }
}
```

n: number of span, content: string content in each span